# Specifying select-before-update with Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to specify the "select-before-update" attribute in a ClassMap using Fluent NHibernate, but I'm not finding much on the web that shows what the right way to do it is. Does anyone know how to achieve this with Fluent NHibernate? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SelectBeforeUpdate()` in your `ClassMap`.

Comment: Heh, I guess we are working with quite an old version of Fluent now! I got the latest version and only feel mildly stupid for asking a question with such an obvious answer :P Thanks